# How do I config nginx to serve any path to a single specific html file?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, prerender

I use Vue and prerender a `index.html`, and the Vue entry file `app.html`. 
I need to configure `nginx` to serve by the following rules:

```
www.mydomain.com/ => go to /data/www/index.html
www.mydomain.com  => go to /data/www/index.html
www.mydomain.com/anything => anything else go to /data/www/app.html
```

Here is what I wrote in `ngnix.conf` but it's not working:

```
server_name www.mydomain.com;
root /data/www/mydomain/;
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html $uri/app.html /app.html ;
}
```

It does not serve `app.html` in any circumstance. 
How do I configure to achieve that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this one?

```
location = / {
    rewrite . /index.html break;
}
location / {
    rewrite . /app.html break;
}
```

Comment: I found out another `location` is the reason why my config in the answer is not working:`location ~ .*.(js|css)$?{expires 30d;}`, I delete the `?` character, and it's working, isn't this location only effective the expires of js and css file ? But after all, your config is working swell too!

Comment: Right regex for js and css files must be looking as `.*\.(js|css)$` (note the slash before last dot).

Comment: And even more simple: `location ~ \.(js|css)$`, but with this location you'll get a 404 error on every request for js of css file that does not exists on your server, and these requests would not be passed to your `app.html`. BTW, my config will have better performance than yours, you could read [this article](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too) for additional details.